# Set the checkbox to checked for input fields in the first 2 table rows

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to set the checkbox to checked for input fields in the first 2 table rows of a table.

markup

```
<tbody>
<tr>
    <td>
     <input type="checkbox" id="" class="checkinput financeOption"><!--want this checked on page load-->
    </td>
      <td class="datatd">
      <label id="">Option 1</label>
    </td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" id="" class="checkinput financeOption"><!--want this checked on page load-->
    </td>
    </td>
    <td class="datatd"><label id="">Option 2 </label>
    </td>   
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
       <input type="checkbox" id="" class="checkinput financeOption">
    </td>
      <td class="datatd"><label id="">Option 3</label>
    </td>   
</tr>
```

I know I can use $( "").prop('checked', true); to set the property but struggling with figureing out how to target the first 2.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to use JavaScript for some reason?  Just do `<input type="checkbox" checked>` - Also, why do you have empty ID's? That doesn't make sense. Also, you shouldn't be using a table for your form.

Comment: 2 valid points. Yes, I could just set it to checked in markup but the table rows get generated from an object (should have mentioned that). My ID's are empty to scrape some data out of my markup for the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example `nth-child(-n+2)` selector:

```
$('table tr:nth-child(-n+2) :checkbox').prop('checked', true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B8h7N/

Answer (score 2):

Just slice them:

```
$("[type=checkbox]").slice(0,2).prop('checked', true);
```